# How to remove the divider from the children of an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, divider

I am making Multi Choice Questions in android. And for that i am using Expandable listview. I don't want to show spaces (dividers) between child views, and also between child and parent view. But i want divider between different expandable listviews. I have search a lot but what i found is that add transparent color between child views but it still shows space between child views. So is there any way to remove the space between the child views. This is my xml code for Expandable listview.

```
<ExpandableListView
 android:id="@+id/list_single_choice_questions"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:dividerHeight="5dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
 android:divider="#ffffff"
 android:childDivider="#00000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:divider` to choose the parent drawable or the `android:footerDividersEnabled` / `android:headerDividersEnabled` might be what you are looking for the parent views. These are all inherited from the ListView parent.

As for child views we can look at Java methods to set it programmatically, see
[Android docs on Expandable List](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setChildDivider(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)). For example setChildDivider() :

> Sets the drawable that will be drawn adjacent to every child in the
>   list. This will be drawn using the same height as the normal divider
>   (setDivider(Drawable)) or if it does not have an intrinsic height, the
>   height set by setDividerHeight(int).

Therefore the height used is set by `setDividerHeight()` or the intrinsic height.

Other than that you could change the child view's xml layout to make the space between each smaller.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/child_list_item"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     <!--no padding or margin-->/>
```

**EDIT:**

You could try creating a `childDividerShape` drawable like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

And then set it to the `android:childDivider` attribute.

```
...
android:childDivider="@drawable/childDividerShape"
...
```

Comment: Nothing worked... When i add android:divider=0dp it will remove space from the childs as well as parents and from multiple expandable views. I just want to remove the space from child views. I try to do it programatically but that also didn't work.

Comment: Sorry to hear, I updated the answer with an edit see if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried the same before but didn't work. To remove the space from child views i have to set divider to 0dp. Which also remove the space from different expandable views.

Answer (score 0):

add two below line in ExpandableListView in xml file

```
android:divider="@null" 
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```